Windows Hello for Business Passwordless logon fails
We have a conference room PC configured for auto-logon.  For the most part it works, however if users turn it off incorrectly, the PC auto-locks and we don't know how to fix it.
And yes, we have done training and put up posts, but users are being users...  It is  Windows 10 Pro.
What we have done:

Set DWORD registry value to 0: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PasswordLess\Device!DevicePasswordLessBuildVersion

Open netplwiz and check if the option appears.
Uncheck the "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer" box;
Confirm with "Apply" and then enter the password/confirmation of the current password and click "OK"

Set DWORD registry value to 1: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Disable autoLock!NoLockScreen

We made sure the PC does not lock when it hibernates by turning that off.

We changed what the power button does to turn off.

Confirmed that turning the computer off results in the computer being locked when powered on.


We are at a bit of a loss here.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!
EDIT - 29-Jul-2024
We did add user name and password to registry as well.
EDIT - 31-Jul-2024
We tried running Autologon v3.10 as well, but got the same result.

Hi, we miss one detail, does it fail to the rrepair/safe's mode ? as the autologin does not work, and you did the autologin with the username and password in the registry too ?

You might want to look at the autologon tool. I think one of the things it does is creates a scheduled task that re-applies the settings on startup and login. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon

@yagmoth555 Correct, we did.

@longneck I will try that, thanks.

@longneck So that software did not help.  The PC autolocked.

Do you mean the computer locks after a few minutes of inactivity? Or that when it's rebooted it does not log in? Because that is two very different things.

At this point, the host seems to function like regular Windows. Windows 10 and 11 can be configured to logon the current session and restart the running applications after Windows restarts, autologon is  technically not required.So the host is only failing to "unlock" the console session...
